# How to close the Modal with simple condition in Reactstrap?

Tags: reactjs, reactstrap

I created Modal for registration. Everything works fine except logic for closing the Modal. What I want is to make condition for closing it.

Condition is: If the user is filled all fields (name, email, etc) and if everything is OK with all that validation, then on button 'Sign Up' close the modal. User is successfully registered.

If the user is not filled all fields or validation is not OK, then on click on button 'Sign Up' don't close modal. Only button 'Close' should close it. User is not registered.

That's it.

But, click on button 'Sign Up' is always closing the Modal, not matter of what condition I wrote.

```
        axios
            .post('/api/users', user, config)
            .then(res => {
                dispatch({ type: 'REGISTER_SUCCESS', payload: res.data })
                props.toggle(false)     //close modal if btn 'Sign Up' is clicked, user is successfully registered                
            })
            .catch(err => {
                setErrorMsg(err.response.data)
                dispatch({ type: "REGISTER_FAILED" })
                props.toggle(true)      //don't close modal if btn 'Sign Up' is clicked, user registration failed
            })
```

Here is code sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/hopeful-star-27wir?file=/src/Register.tsx

Comment: You can add ```disabled``` property to sign up button.. Does this resolves your issue? https://codesandbox.io/s/modern-pond-zm25y?file=/src/Register.tsx

Comment: yes, I didn't want to disable it but sure,  it's working , thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

toggle(), which is toggleSignUp() does not receive any params, so toggle(true) does not make sense. Just comment toggle(true) and it will not be closed.

```
axios
  .post("/api/users", user, config)
  .then(res => {
    props.toggle(false); //close modal if btn 'Sign Up' is clicked, user is successfully registered
  })
  .catch(err => {
    setErrorMsg(err.response.data);
    // COMMENt THIS
    //props.toggle(true); //don't close modal if btn 'Sign Up' is clicked, user registration failed
  });
```

Or you can fix the toggleSignUp() to receive params:

```
  const toggleSignUp = (close:boolean) => {
    if(typeof close === 'boolean') {
      setModalSignUp(close);
    } else {
      setModalSignUp(!modalSignUp);
    }
  }
```